# Usage of libvirt rpc protocol

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, rpc

Where libvirt rpc protocol is used? Is it used inside remote connection communication?
I have read that it used between libvirt library and libvirt daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The libvirt RPC protocol is a private communications protocol allowing the libvirt.so library to talk to libvirtd daemon. It is not intended for end users to directly access the RPC protocol - the client library libvirt.so is the only supported way of interacting with libvirtd.